# insert images coming from more than input file

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-8

And I have a problem with how to insert images into the database, if there are input fields that increase or decrease in the case of addition or deletion

[image]

I created a function to enter data from the fields, but the problem is in the line responsible for uploading images
Note: I put the lines inside for ($i=0; $i<count($products); $i++)
Because the lines may increase or decrease, and I am displaying the data in the form of an array

```php
$products = $request->day_book_id;
for ($i=0; $i<count($products); $i++) {
    $items = new Daybooks_units();

    $items->debit= $request->debit[$i];
    $items->creditor= $request->creditor[$i];
    $items->data= $request->data[$i];
    $items->reference= $request->reference[$i];
//here the problem input name =images[]
    $items->files= ;
//here the problem


    $items->dayBook_code= $request->dayBook_code[$i];
    $items->fullAccounting_id= $request->fullAccounting_id[$i];
    $items->day_book_id= $request->day_book_id[$i];
    $items->branch_id= $request->branch_id[$i];
    $items->save();
```

This is the code for the blade

```html
<td style="padding:3px" >
    <input type="text" class="search" name="search" required>

    <select class="form-control search_list getData" id="search_list"  name="fullAccounting_id[]"></select>
    @error('fullAccounting_id')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</td>
<td style="display:none" >
    <input type="text" value=" " class=" form-control putParentId" name="ParentOfAccounting_manual_id[]">
</td>
<td style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value=" " class=" form-control putCode" name="code_accountingManuals[]">
</td>
<td style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value=" " class=" form-control debtor_creditor" name="debtor_creditor[]">
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="text" value="0" class=" form-control totaldebit" onchange="getTotalRowPrice(this , '{{-500}}' )" name="debit[]">
    @error('debit')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</td>
<td style="width:100px;">
    <input type="text" onchange="getTotalRowPrice(this , '{{-500}}' )" value="0" class=" form-control totalcreditor" name="creditor[]">
    @error('creditor')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="text" value="" class=" form-control" name="data[]">
</td>
<td style="width:100px;">
    <select name="branch_id[]" required class="form-control">
        <option></option>
        @foreach($costCenters as $costCent)
            <option value="{{$costCent->id}}">{{$costCent->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @error('branch_id')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="reference[]" value="">
</td>
<td style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="id_unit[]" value="{{ $id_unit }}">
</td>
<td style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="daybooks_units[]" value="daybooks_units">
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple class="form-control" id="customFile">
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="add" id="add" value="add" style="color: white">
</td>
```

//the js code to add more rows of input

```
$('#add').click(function(){
  var  size = $('#table_field tbody').children().length +1;
        var html = '<tr>'+'<td style="padding:3px"  >'+size+'</td>'+'<td style="display:none;"><input type="text" value="{{$id}}"  class=" form-control"  name="day_book_id[]"><td style="display:none;"> <input   type="text" name="tablename[]" class="form-control"   value="day_books"></td><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" class="form-control " name="daybooks_units[]" value="daybooks_units"></td></td><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" class="form-control " name="id_unit[]" value="{{$id_unit}}"></td><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" value="{{$myId}}"  class=" form-control totalprice"  name="dayBook_code[]"></td><td style="padding:3px"  ><input type="text" required   class="search" name="search"><select  class="form-control search_list getData" name="fullAccounting_id[]" ></select></td><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" value=" " name="ParentOfAccounting_manual_id[]" class=" form-control putParentId"  ></td><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" value=" " name="code_accountingManuals[]" class=" form-control putCode"  ></td><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" value=" " class=" form-control debtor_creditor"  name="debtor_creditor[]"></td><td style="padding:3px"  ><input type="text" class=" form-control totaldebit" onchange="getTotalRowPrice(this ,'+size+')" value="0" name="debit[]"></td><td style="padding:3px"  ><input type="text" onchange="getTotalRowPrice(this ,'+size+')" value="" class="form-control totalcreditor" name="creditor[]"></td><td style="padding:3px"  ><input type="text" class="form-control " name="data[]"></td><td style="width:100px;"><select name="branch_id[]" required class="form-control"><option></option>@foreach($costCenters as $costCent)<option value="{{$costCent->id}}">{{$costCent->name}}</option>@endforeach</select>@error('branch_id')<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{$message}}</div> @enderror</td><td style="padding:3px"  ><input type="text" class="form-control " name="reference[]"></td><td style="padding:3px"  ><input  type="file" name="files[]" class="form-control" id="customFile" /></td><td style="padding:3px"  ><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="remove" id="remove" value="حذف" style="color:white;"></td></tr>';
    $('#table_field').append(html);
});
```

Comment: ___the error appears___ Can you show us the error then please

Comment: Useful information in the manual https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem

Comment: The whole idea is that I don't know how to store images. I modified my own question

Comment: Thank you, but it does not explain how to insert images if there is more than one input file

Comment: _The whole idea of a user manual_ - To find out how to do things you currently dont know how to do

Comment: Or a search will provide you [many things to read](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stackoverflow%3A+laravel+upload+multiple+files&t=newext&atb=v362-2&ia=web)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this information to me, but the manual shows how to upload only one image, but it does not help me with my problem, so I ask for help in that case
And I thank you again for your efforts, and I ask you if you know the solution to this scenario, I ask you to share with me the solution or the idea, but if you do not know, then thank you again for your efforts

Comment: `$files = $request->file('images');` Then `$files` will be an array, one occurance per file uploaded

Comment: Do you mean like thisway                    $files = $request->file('images');
                $items->files = $files[$i];, because I tried it and all it did was insert one value into the first image like this /tmp/php19tWip, and that the code was executed once, and only the first row was entered

Comment: do `$files = $request->file('images');` and then `dd($files);` to see what you have in that array

Comment: it return one array  array:1 [▼
  0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#2118 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "200.JPG"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpldSbRo"
    basename: "phpldSbRo"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpldSbRo"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpldSbRo"

  }
]

Comment: There you go, an array of `$_FILES` occurances. So write a loop and process them one by one inside the loop

Comment: inside my for  i put this 
                                           $items->files= $request->file('images')->store('avatars')[$i];
                                 its show me this error  
Call to a member function store() on array